# Why does void** cause a seg fault in this case?

Tags: c

I am confused why this code causes a seg fault

```
int array[] = {1, 2};
void** ptr = (void**) &array;
printf("%d", *(int*)ptr[0]);
```

I expected it to print the int stored at array[0] but for it seg faults instead.

Comment: Did you assume that an array stores pointers to its elements?

Comment: `void**` means a pointer to a `void*` pointer, which could be a decayed array of `void*` pointers. You don't have an array of pointers, you have an array of integers.

Comment: You're trying to dereference `1` and `2` as pointers, assuming `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)`

Comment: `void*` can be used as a generic pointer, but that doesn't mean you can use `void**` as a generic pointer to an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what you expected to see, you seem to be under the impression that an array is a pointer.  It is not.

An array will *decay* into a pointer in most contexts, but is not a pointer.  It is a contiguous set of values.  This also means that the address of an array will be the same as the address of the first value, although their types will be different.

On this line:

```
void** ptr = (void**) &array;
```

You take the address of the array (which is the same as the address of the first member) and assign it to `ptr`.

Now let's break down what you're trying to print:

```
*(int*)ptr[0]
```

You're taking `ptr` which has type `void **` and you dereference it via the array index operator with `ptr[0]`.  This by itself is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you're trying to access an array of type `int[2]` as a `void *`.  While a `void *` can be used as a generic pointer type, that does not extend to `void **`.

But assuming this works as "expected", you now have an expression of type `void *` whose value are the bytes of the array.  If you print `ptr[0]` with the `%p` format specifier, you'll likely see "0x200000001" printed (assuming your machine is little endian.

You then take the pointer value 0x200000001, convert it to a `int *`, and dereference it.  As this pointer value is likely not a valid value, you get a segfault when you attempt to dereference it.

Had you used `void *` as follows:

```
void *ptr = array;
printf("%d", *(int*)ptr);
```

Or even:

```
void *ptr = &array;
printf("%d", *(int*)ptr);
```

You would have gotten the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from a very common misunderstanding. `array` is not a pointer, it only behaves like pointer in expressions (it is called decaying). When you use `&array` you are getting the same reference as you were using `array` or `&array[0]`, but with different type - pointer to array.

Basically, you read the memory where integers are stored, convert this value to a pointer and then dereference it.

You can see it in this example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {1, 2};
    void** ptr = (void**) array;
    printf("%p", (void *)ptr[0]);
}
```

The result (as you see pointers are 64 bits in this implementation:

```
0x200000001
```

You need to store the references of the elements in the array of void pointers to use it your way:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {1, 2};
    void **ptr = (void *[]){array, array + 1};
    printf("%d", *(int *)ptr[0]);
}
```

Comment: I have read the whole answer, but I need to change my wording in my comment. As you answered it first, I was unable to correct it. I'll delete my comment and once you have deleted yours, I'll delete also this comment.  Sorry but I was interrupted while I was writting and the time to change the comment elapsed.  Just to comment that despite having the same VALUE, two references with different pointed to types are DIFFERENT references.

Answer (score 0):

Array subscription (`[0]`) [binds more tightly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the cast. This treats the first element in the array as a pointer, and then that pointer is ultimately dereferenced. This surely invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The types used are incorrect. `&array` has the type `int (*)[2]`, which is incompatible with a `void **`.

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = { 1, 2 };
    void *ptr = &array;
    printf("%d\n", (*(int (*)[2]) ptr)[0]);
}
```

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

let's analise the expression `*(int*)ptr[0]` in the context:

```
int array[] = {1, 2};
void** ptr = (void**) &array;
printf("%d", *(int*)ptr[0]);
```

`ptr[0]` is the integer `1` (the first element of your array) It's of type `int`.  You cast it to a pointer to int, and then dereference it.  You are trying to get what is stored at address 1? (well, the result of that is not defined by the language, it's not clear that convertng an integer to an address is going to give you something useful) (ideed, you incurr in Undefined behaviour when trying to dereference, and so, any compiler can give you a different response, the code is in error and the intention you had becomes a mistery, or nothing at all --A SIGSEGV is an example of this--)

To access that address you need your operating system to have mapped into your virtual address space the address `0x01`, which is not normally the case (most operating systems today expressely unmap that address to protect you from dereferencing the `NULL` pointer, and so, addresses in [0x0000..0x01000] are expressely unallocated, this includes the address you are using)

By the way, there's no pointer in your array, so why you are converting some part of an array into a pointer and dereferencing it is a mistery for me.  Had you explained what you are trying to do, probably I could help a bit more.

Answer (score -3):

The Correct Code would be:

```
int arr[] = {1,2};
void *ptr = &arr;
printf("%d\n",*(int*)ptr);
```

When you initialize the arr pointer by [], you create a single dimension array which will have {1,2}, now for initializing another pointer that will hold the address of the first pointer you dont need a ** you just need one, because is one pointer you are holding in that array. now as for the printing of value[0] of your arr, that no need to place a value as when you print the ptr value automatically prints the first value of the arr only as per C language specification.

Comment: `arr` s not a pointer. The rest of the explanation is completely wrong.

Comment: arr[] = *arr its a pointer to an array in C

Comment: @MSWA no it isn't; that's a common beginner misunderstanding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957

Comment: `&arr` doesn't make the array "decay" into a pointer to the first element as it most often does. Therefore the type of `&arr` is `int(*)[2]`, a pointer to array. This type is actually not compatible with `int*`. _However_, this code will work but not for the reasons you expect. It will work because C allows you to access data through a de-referenced pointer ("lvalue access") as long as it has the type corresponding to the pointed-data. The actual data stored is an `int` and so you can access it through a `int*` even if that pointer was obtained from an invalid pointer conversion.